# Unable to disable form element with jquery as per faq example

Tags: jquery, forms

I've been trying to disable a form element using jquery, as per the example in the [FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F)

Here is my attempt so far.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action ="process.php" method ="post" >
<p>Room type:<br />
<input type="radio" name="roomtype" value="mdorm" onClick="$('#roomnumber').attr('disabled','disabled')">Mixed Dorm<br>
<input type="radio" name="roomtype" value="fdorm" onClick="$('#roomnumber').attr('disabled','disabled')">Female Dorm<br>
<input type="radio" name="roomtype" value="room">Private Room<br>
</p>
<p>Room number<br />
<select name="roomnumber">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

However, clicking any radio button never results in the drop downl list being disabled. I've followed the example essentially verbatim, so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jquery is using the id selector # but your  doesn't have an id attribute.
`<select id="roomnumber">` should help

Answer (score 1):

You are using ID selector, but your select element doesn't have ID attribute:

```
<select id="roomnumber" name="roomnumber">
```

As of jQuery 1.6 for enabling/disabling form elements(*or modifying other properties*)  `prop` method should be used instead of `attr` method, change your markup to:

```
<p>Room type:<br />
   <input type="radio" name="roomtype" value="mdorm">Mixed Dorm<br>
   <input type="radio" name="roomtype" value="fdorm">Female Dorm<br>
   <input type="radio" name="roomtype" value="room">Private Room<br>
</p>
```

And you can code:

```
$(function(){ // document ready handler
    $('input[name="roomtype"]').change(function(){ // listen to the change event
        // disable the select element if value of radio group is not 'room'
        $('#roomnumber').prop('disabled', this.value !== 'room')
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Er8zX/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="roomnumber" id="roomnumber">
```

maybe?

Comment: Consider adding some explanation why this solves the problem at hand and why it is a better solution than the accepted answer.